# Metric Tensor in Weak Field Condition

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, approximations, linearized-theory

Suppose that we are in the *Weak Field Condition*, that is:
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta _{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$
where $\eta _{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor of flat space time (Minkowski spacetime) and $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a perturbation such that:
$$|h_{\mu\nu}|<<1$$
Perfect. But now I would like to find the tensor $g^{\mu\nu}$; *by definition* (it is by definition of $g^{\mu\nu}$, right?) we have:
$$g_{\mu\lambda}g^{\lambda \nu}=\delta ^\nu _\mu$$
I am fine with all the above, but now it is said that from the previous equation we can derive that:
$$g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-h^{\mu\nu}$$
**why?** Can you show me the process behind this result?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295005/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/446667/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The question in the cited post is different. It's only the same topic.

Comment: @Noumeno,  up to first order,  the inverse metric is what you have mentioned.